# SAS log output when clicking on SAS datset

Tags: logging, sas

Everytime I click to open a SAS dataset, it gives me this long list of log that I don't need. How do I get rid of it? It seems simple enough, but I just don't know how to do it..this is the log that it generates every time I click and open a dataset

```
 ERROR: Bad record length for entry VT_PRINTLIST.SLIST in catalog   
 SASUSER.PROFILE.
 No memory available
 Arguments passed to FILLIST:
1 (Character Literal) = 'catalog'
2 (Character Literal) = 'sasuser.profile.vt_printList.slist'
3 (Numeric Expression $T3) = 10027
Program returning prematurely at line 374
AF Program: SASHELP.FSP.DATAVIEW.SCL
absrow = .
access = ''
applid = .
attach = .
attrlist = .
bottom = .
bottomMargin = .
.
.
.
.
.and on and on.
```

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted installation (or corrupted profile) to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be a support ticket to SAS rather than a question here.

Comment: only one sas dataset or every dataset? give a try with sashelp library datasets.

Comment: It's every sas dataset

Answer (score 1):

Giving a fast search on google I found this:

My guess is your SASUSER.PROFILE catalog has been corrupted. Close SAS and try renaming this catalog to another name such as profile_old using Windows Explorer. Start SAS and it should create a new, clean SASUSER.PROFILE catalog.
In addition to this also delete the file 'sasuser.profile.vt_printList.slist'.

And the result obtained was positive in that case, hope it will help you.
Good Luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you for writing this. I experienced the exact same problem 4 year later so I am happy that this is still here. I was not able to find the sasuser.profile in my windows. However renaming the 'sasuser.profile.vt_printList.slist' into 'sasuser.profile.vt_printList.slist_old' could be done inside SAS and that also worked, so thanks!

Comment: Nevertheless if you read this and can tell me where in Windows the SASUSER.PROFILE is hidden I am still curious!